# How to set image as background

Tags: media

I am using bartik theme. I have an image that I like to use as background of the home page only. Admin > appearance > Bartik > settings > I see different colors to set as background. Can I have an image as background instead of the color for the home page. And for other pages I can use a color.

Thanks.

D

Answer (score 0):

unless you want to add it to a theme setting so that it can be adjusted by UI, the simplest way is probably to override `page--front.tpl.php` in your theme template directory, and manually add the html to create the background.

For more info on page template naming, see [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2354645).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module. From its project page (bold markup added here):

> ... allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
> rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
> path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
> properties.
>
> In combination with Drupal's theme inheritance you can easily achieve features like:
>
> - a front-page / "splash" screen
> - ...

So by [creating a subtheme](https://www.drupal.org/node/225125) of the Bartik theme to be used on the home page, and another subtheme for all other pages, it should achieve your goal, no?

Comment: Any feedback about this answer?